# CURL function returns null in php

Tags: php, curl, zendesk

I am trying to fetch some data from my zendesk account as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://testing136.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/me.json");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "mymail@gmail.com/token:apikey");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $decoded = json_decode($output);
        print("Decode ".$decoded);
```

I have double checked the parameters and data but nothing is returned. I just get Null although I tried to curl in the cmd and it was done successfully.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Its probably due to a misseting in php config

Comment: @Etixpp
could you clarify a bit more?!

Comment: `curl_exec` [cannot return null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php). It returns `false` or, with `RETURNTRANSFER` enabled, the content. If nothing is returned, use [`curl_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to find out the problem.

Comment: I would btw if I were you VERY QUICKLY INVALIDATE THAT TOKEN that you copy/pasted in this code before everyone on Stack Overflow starts reading your Gmail. Editing it out here isn't enough since everyone can see the edit history, and about 10000 people can even see deleted topics.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I got the following
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateDecode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Could you explain about this and tell how we can improve the webserver to prevent adding this bypass? Anyway it saved my day, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

//Just Remove line no. 267 of application/libraries/REST_Controller.php in Codeigniter

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```